# What to use instead of div elements in HTML5

Tags: html, styles

I read in the HTML5 specification that the generic `div` tag should only be used as "last resort," when a more specific element is unavailable. For example, the tags `header`, `footer` and `section` are preferred for grouping content thematically.

But it seems like the vast majority of websites still use `div` as the primary element. My question is, how often and in what contexts is it appropriate to use a `div`? And which other elements should be used in its place?

I'm looking for answers based on the specification rather than personal opinions. Thanks!

Comment: The vast majority of websites were built before HTML5 became widely accepted. Have you looked at the specs for the new elements? Their intended purposes are pretty clear.

Comment: This is a pretty good article I came across http://html5doctor.com/you-can-still-use-div/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There isn't anything that takes the place of `<div>` (theres a reason its still in the spec), but HTML5 has more elements available that are more specific.

In addition to `<header>`, `<footer>`, and `<section>` there is:

- `<nav>`
- `<article>`
- `<aside>`
- `<main>`
- `<details>`
- `<summary>`
- `<figure>`
- `<dialog>`
- `<menu>`
- and more!

Basically any new HTML5 element can take the place of a `<div>`.

When should you use a div? You answered it yourself:

> when a more specific element is unavailable

MDN has a [HTML5 element list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list) which contains all standard HTML5 elements, and indicates which elements are new with HTML5.

Comment: Do these offer any advantages outside of being more explicit for the code reader?

Answer (score 3):

The thing to remember is that `div` tag is still a part of HTML5 and it’s not obsolete, yet.
However, `div` element has been abused a lot with HTML4, and rightfully so as there were never any alternates to it. Now that HTML5 has included some great new structural elements, `div` is no longer the best option for creating layouts.

The main disadvantage with `div` is that the element has no meaning due to which creating application-ready layouts is very difficult. The new structural elements introduced in HTML5 will surely help a lot with that issue.

The `section` element will most likely be used more than the other structural elements like `header`, `footer` etc. mainly because it is not specific as others. Also there is no limit as to how many structural elements you can add but the thing to remember is that `section` is not a complete `div` replacement.

`div` still has a role in HTML5. It is great for grouping similar elements as well as dividing elements as needed. Also `section` should not be used just for styling because `section` was not intended to be a wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `header`, `section`, `footer`, and other such elements were created is to help with referencing them in css and scripting languages. W3C looked at the most common IDs web developers were using for `div`s and made the new elements in HTML5 accordingly. The reason `div`s and IDs is widely considered bad practice is because all those attributes clutters up the code. And as we all know, cluttered coding leads to mistakes and errors.

Where do you use them? That's pretty self explanatory. Take the `header` for example. It's most common use is the top of the web page. Right click on the stack overflow logo at the top and view the source. They're actually using a `div` with an ID of 'header'. Technically, that's bad practice.

A great use for `div`s is to create a wrapper around your entire content like this.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!--content-->
</div>
```

Then you can reference it in css to center:

```
#wrapper{margin:20px auto;}
```

Hoped this helped!